# почему бот не работает постоянно,

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

```
from imaplib import Commands
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('5724116823:AAE4c-ZEAWoEPb5eKzH9CKcalWKSiPV1gsM')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess=f'Привет, <b>{message.from_user.first_name}</b>'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,mess,parse_mode='html')

@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == "Привет":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'и тебе привет!',parse_mode='html')
    else:
          bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'я тебя не понимаю, занимался боксом',parse_mode='html')  
    

bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и что у вас не работает?

Comment: бот работает примерно мин 10, потом он не выдает не каких запросов и ответов)в тг

Comment: VSCode закрываете?

Comment: Код полностью рабочий, проблема если и есть, то точно не в нем

Answer (score 0):

**Попробуй добавить такую схему:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: а при закрытии VSCode бот должен работать ?

Comment: Если ты запустил его напрямую через файл, а не VS Code, то при закрытии VS Code должен работать.